# Is it right way to make text-protocol interpretation program?

Tags: parsing, boost, text, split, protocols

I'm trying to make a program for parsing text protocol.
(I selected text protocol cause I heard that binary packet parsing is more difficult).
Currently, there are really few command and parameters.

> each packet can be splited by delimiter(';')
>   [packet1];[packet2];

Let's break packet1 down.

> [Action],[Param1],[Param2],...;
>
> Action : [SET]
>   Params : [DELAY]

if you send "SET,DELAY,300;" to server,
server will change 'delay' parameter and send "SET,DELAY,300;" to client.

> Action : [GET]
>   Params : [DELAY] [MODE]

if you send "GET,DELAY,MODE;" to server,
server will send "GET,DELAY,300,MODE,2;" to client.

Any way I suceed to make it.
[(The code is here](http://www.devpia.com/MAEUL/Contents/Detail.aspx?BoardID=50&MAEULNO=20&no=947627&ref=947627&page=1). because it is long, I couldn't add it here)
But even if there are only few params and actions, the code is very long and complicated.

I used 'boost::algorithm::split' to split packets.
And I only used 'if','else if','else' to invoke right task corresponding 'action' and 'parameter'.

But I will add more actions and parameters. 
But at this rate, I cannot debug or modify code because the comlexity of the code will be more severe.

Is it wrong way to make protocol translation program?

If you know better way, please share with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The better way is to make a grammar, write a parser for it and parse into an AST (abstract syntax tree, or simply strong typed representation of the packets).

A Spirit grammar for this looks like:

1. I always start out with the AST types:

   ```
   namespace ast {

       struct nil {
           friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, nil) { return os << "<nil>"; }
       };

       using value = boost::variant<nil, double, std::string>;

       struct parameter {
           std::string _key;
           value       _val;
       };

       enum class action {
           get, 
           set,
       };

       using parameters = std::vector<parameter>;

       struct packet {
           action      _action;
           parameters  _params;
       };

       using packets = std::vector<packet>;
   }
   ```

   For simplicity I've

   - assumed parameters (mode/delay) will have numeric or string values.
   - used the same packet definition for `GET` and `SET` requests (`GET` requests will just us `nil` values for the parameters listed)
2. Next we define a grammar using Boost Spirit Qi:

   ```
   template <typename It, typename Skipper=qi::space_type>
   struct grammar : qi::grammar<It, ast::packets(), Skipper> {

       grammar():grammar::base_type(start) {
           using qi::raw;
           using qi::no_case;

           param_key_.add
               ("delay")
               ("mode");

           start      = *(packet_ >> ';');

           packet_    = 
               (no_case["get"] >> qi::attr(ast::action::get) >> *(',' >> get_param_))
               | (no_case["set"] >> qi::attr(ast::action::set) >> *(',' >> set_param_))
               ;

           get_param_ = raw[no_case[param_key_]] >> qi::attr(ast::nil());
           set_param_ = raw[no_case[param_key_]] >> "," >> value_;

           value_     = qi::double_ | string_;
           string_    = '"' >> *~qi::char_('"') >> '"';

           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(packet_)(get_param_)(set_param_)(value_)(string_))
       }
       // ... field declarations
   };
   ```

   There's a little bit of a learning curve here, but the key point to observe is that it it's possible to create maintainable code that is **[also debuggable (see here for `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG` enabled output)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9554333/)**.
3. Finally, because the AST is simple we can make a fake request processor that uses a request context (in this case a map to contain the current values of the parameters) to actually process the requests:

   ```
   struct request_context {

       std::map<std::string, ast::value> properties;

       request_context() 
           : properties { { "MODE", 2 }, { "DELAY", 300 } } // defaults
       {
       }

       boost::optional<ast::packet> process_request(ast::packet packet) {
           switch (packet._action) {
               case ast::action::get:
                   for(auto& param : packet._params) {
                       param._val = properties[param._key];
                   }
                   return packet;
               case ast::action::set:
                   for(auto& param : packet._params) {
                       std::cout << "DEBUG: setting property '" << param._key << "' to value '" << param._val << "'\n";
                       properties[param._key] = param._val;
                   }
                   return boost::none;
               default:
                   throw std::runtime_error("bad packet"); // TODO proper exception type
           };
       }
   };
   ```

   Imagine who much messier this was if you had it mixed with the parsing code, or everything **[*stringly typed*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped)**

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9a2498531e42df1)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <map>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace ast {

    struct nil {
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, nil) { return os << "<nil>"; }
    };

    using value = boost::variant<nil, double, std::string>;

    struct parameter {
        std::string _key;
        value       _val;
    };

    enum class action {
        get, 
        set,
    };

    using parameters = std::vector<parameter>;

    struct packet {
        action      _action;
        parameters  _params;
    };

    using packets = std::vector<packet>;

    static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, action a) { 
        switch(a) {
            case action::get: return os << "GET"; 
            case action::set: return os << "SET"; 
        }
        return os << "(other)"; 
    }
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::parameter,(std::string,_key)(ast::value,_val))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::packet,(ast::action,_action)(ast::parameters,_params))

template <typename It, typename Skipper=qi::space_type>
   struct grammar : qi::grammar<It, ast::packets(), Skipper> {

       grammar():grammar::base_type(start) {
           using qi::raw;
           using qi::no_case;

           param_key_.add
               ("delay")
               ("mode");

           start      = *(packet_ >> ';');

           packet_    = 
               (no_case["get"] >> qi::attr(ast::action::get) >> *(',' >> get_param_))
             | (no_case["set"] >> qi::attr(ast::action::set) >> *(',' >> set_param_))
             ;

           get_param_ = raw[no_case[param_key_]] >> qi::attr(ast::nil());
           set_param_ = raw[no_case[param_key_]] >> "," >> value_;

           value_     = qi::double_ | string_;
           string_    = '"' >> *~qi::char_('"') >> '"';

           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(packet_)(get_param_)(set_param_)(value_)(string_))
       }

    private:

       qi::symbols<char, std::string> param_key_;
       qi::rule<It, ast::parameter(), Skipper> set_param_, get_param_;
       qi::rule<It, ast::packets(),   Skipper> start;
       qi::rule<It, ast::packet(),    Skipper> packet_;
       qi::rule<It, ast::value(),     Skipper> value_;
       qi::rule<It, std::string()>             string_;
   };

struct request_context {

    std::map<std::string, ast::value> properties;

    request_context() 
        : properties { { "MODE", 2 }, { "DELAY", 300 } } // defaults
    {
    }

    boost::optional<ast::packet> process_request(ast::packet packet) {
        switch (packet._action) {
            case ast::action::get:
                for(auto& param : packet._params) {
                    param._val = properties[param._key];
                }
                return packet;
            case ast::action::set:
                for(auto& param : packet._params) {
                    std::cout << "DEBUG: setting property '" << param._key << "' to value '" << param._val << "'\n";
                    properties[param._key] = param._val;
                }
                return boost::none;
            default:
                throw std::runtime_error("bad packet"); // TODO proper exception type
        };
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string const input = 
            "GET,DELAY,MODE;" 
            "SET,DELAY,0,MODE,\"we can have string values too\";GET,MODE;SET,MODE,42;GET,MODE,DELAY;";

    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    It f(input.begin()), l(input.end());

    grammar<It> p;
    ast::packets parsed;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,qi::space,parsed);

    if (ok) {
        std::cout << parsed.size() << " packets successfully parsed\n";

        request_context ctx;

        for(auto& packet : parsed)
        {
            auto response = ctx.process_request(packet);

            if (response) {
                std::cout << "response: " << response->_action;
                for(auto& kv : packet._params) {
                    std::cout << "," << kv._key << "," << kv._val;
                }
                std::cout << ";\n";
            }
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse error\n";
    }

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
5 packets successfully parsed
response: GET,DELAY,300,MODE,2;
DEBUG: setting property 'DELAY' to value '0'
DEBUG: setting property 'MODE' to value 'we can have string values too'
response: GET,MODE,we can have string values too;
DEBUG: setting property 'MODE' to value '42'
response: GET,MODE,42,DELAY,0;
```